# geoNear stage must be first

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Hey i have been playing around with mongodb geo api and it seems quite limiting, most notably the limitation that does not allow any other stage to be executed before it, i have only came across possible solution `$facet` but it limits `geoNear` stage as well, so i am out of options, what i need is to use `$match` stage before `$geoNear`, i know that `$geoNear` has it's own query but geoNear's `coordinates` here's my current code

```
  {
    $match: {/*query*/},
  },
  {
    $geoNear: {
      near: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: '$geometry.coordinates' as unknown as [number, number],
      },
      distanceField: 'dist.calculated',
      maxDistance: 1000000,
      includeLocs: 'dist.location',
      spherical: true,
    },
  },
```

i know this is not a bug but a feature as mongodb contributors say but i really need to get around this somehow and perform matching first

Answer (score 0):

The `$geoNear` aggregation stage was designed for *filter* documents.  It requires a geo-spatial index in order to do that.

An index helps to locate documents within the collection's data files.  The first stage of an aggregation pipeline retrieves the documents and  passes them to the second stage in the pipeline.

This means that the second, and subsequent, stages cannot use an index, because the index would indicate where to find the documents in the original collection, not in the pipeline.

It appears that you have crafted a `$geoNear` stage that will match every possible point on Earth.

Assuming the intent of this is to calculate the distance from the reference point, you may find it faster to calculate the distance on the client side.

If you need the distance for further stages in the pipeline, you might be able to implement the [haversine](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) formulate using the trigonometric functions added in MongoDB 4.2.